# Error in parallel process using doSNOW

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

`Error in { : task 1 failed - "invalid connection"`

Why do I get this error, every time when I try to use all 4 cores for a parallel process.

Here is the example code:

```
NumberOfCluster <- 4
cl <- makeCluster(NumberOfCluster)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

fl<- file(file.choose(),"r") # file.choose() is going to locate a file(.tsv)                 
                             # of size 8 gb (RAM is 4 GB)

foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% {

  View(name_fil <- read.delim(fl,nrows = 1000000,header = TRUE))

}
```

Comment: `View` is an rstudio function to view data within the UI. It seems a little odd to want to call that within code being run on separate processes within a cluster. Also, your look just seems to read the same file 3 times in parallel which is again an odd use of parallelisation.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting an error because file objects can't be exported to the workers. Instead, you could export the name of the file and open that file on each of the workers:

```
fname <- file.choose()
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% {
  fl <- file(fname, "r")
  View(name_fil <- read.delim(fl,nrows = 1000000,header = TRUE))
}
```

You may run into problems using the `View` function next, but this should solve the "invalid connection" error.